# MLE and standard error of $\lambda$ given $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-error

Suppose $x_1 ... x_n$ are an iid sample from the exponential distribution with density:
$$
p(x) = \lambda^{-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}}.
$$
Derive the MLE for $\lambda$ and its standard error.

My calculation:

$$\begin{align}L(\lambda;x) &= \prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i;\lambda) = \lambda^{-n}e^{-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx}{\lambda}} \\ &= \log L(\lambda;x) = -
n\log(\lambda) -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx}{\lambda} \\ &= \frac{\partial \log L(\lambda;x)}{\partial \lambda} \implies \lambda = \bar{x} \\ 
&=\frac{\partial^2 \log L(\lambda;x)}{\partial \lambda}  = \frac{n}{\lambda^2}-\frac{2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{\lambda^3} \end{align}  $$

By taking the fisher information:

$$I(\hat{\lambda}) = -E\left(\frac{n}{\lambda^2}-\frac{2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{\lambda^3} \right)=-\frac{2n}{\lambda^2}$$

If I have my calculations correct, then I cannot see how I can get the standard error if $se = I(\hat{\lambda})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution check in the bottom under Parameter estimation (The maximum likelihood)

Comment: @AlbertParadek thanks for sharing this with me! I have not revised this option. I just had a look at [fishers information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) article on wiki, and it mentions: -"If log f(x; θ) is twice differentiable with respect to θ, and under certain regularity conditions, then the Fisher information may also be written as" the following distribution I gave. Do you know what these "regularity conditions" are - which explains why I could not use it?

Comment: There are some typos in your likelihood (shouldn't $\lambda^{-n/2}$ be $\lambda^{-n}$ instead?) but I think your expression $\hat{\lambda} = \bar{x}$ is correct. From here, don't you simply need to compute the standard deviation of the sample mean?

Comment: @angryavian thanks for pointing this out - I did not do this on paper where I got the calculation from. Not sure what happened :/ that's definitely one alternative - however, I'm looking to understand the use of fishers information in such cases by working with mainly MLE

Comment: @Workingdollar The Fisher information is relevant when discussing the *asymptotic* behavior of the MLE as $n \to \infty$. This can be useful when there is not a simple expression for the variance of the MLE for fixed $n$ (in which case you approximate with the asymptotic variance), but in this case it is easy to compute the exact variance for any $n$.

Comment: @angryavian brilliant explanation! I'll keep to the simpler derivation for the se. However, my mention to Albert Paradek, might you perhaps know the "regularity conditions" that determine whether to use the above fisher information, or the alternative which uses the integral? Such as, whether there is something to notice in the density function, or second derivative (the functions behaviour) to help make the choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you can't have negative information.

Your likelihood is $$\mathcal L(\lambda \mid \boldsymbol x) \propto \lambda^{-n} e^{-n \bar x/\lambda} \mathbb 1(x_{(1)} \ge 0)$$ where I have written this in terms of the sufficient statistic $\bar x$.  Then the log-likelihood is
$$\ell(\lambda \mid \boldsymbol x) = -n \log \lambda - \frac{n \bar x}{\lambda},$$ and
$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \lambda} = -\frac{n}{\lambda} + \frac{n\bar x}{\lambda^2}.$$  The second derivative is
$$\frac{\partial^2 \ell}{\partial \lambda^2} = \frac{n}{\lambda^2} - \frac{2n \bar x}{\lambda^3}.$$  Then your Fisher information is
$$I(\hat \lambda) = - \left( \frac{n}{\lambda^2} - \frac{2n \operatorname{E}[\bar x]}{\lambda^3} \right) = - \frac{n}{\lambda^2} + \frac{2n \lambda}{\lambda^3} = \frac{n}{\lambda^2}.$$

That said, the standard error of $\hat \lambda$ is simply
$$\operatorname{SE}(\hat \lambda) = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\bar x]} \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \sqrt{\frac{\operatorname{Var}[X]}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda^2}{n}} = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{n}}.$$  There is no need to calculate the Fisher information.

Comment: I'm making errors again ... thanks for clarifying - I should have double checked. This then works because $I(\hat{\lambda}) = \frac{n}{\lambda^2} \implies I(\hat{\lambda})^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{n}}$